# HTML Table With Fixed Cells When Resolution Changes

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, cell

I have the following table. The problem is that when you zoom in/out or when the resolution is different, the headers change size. How can I make them stay constant? I want everything to be on one line only. Currently, if there's more than one word in the header (i.e. Response Comment Num) and the headers change size - words bunch up together one underneath the other.

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%;border-collapse: collapse;" cellSpacing="2" cellPadding="2" >
<tr>
<th  style="border:0px solid gray;background:#AAAAAA;color:white;font-weight:700;width:10%">Response Komment #</th>
<th  style="border:0px solid gray;background:#AAAAAA;color:white;font-weight:700;width:60%;">Comment</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind giving the cells a total width of 70%?

Comment: There is 4 more headers that I did not include for clarity sake...

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

to your "style" attributes (which probably should be in some separate CSS file).

Answer (score 0):

Give the first header more width to avoid wrapping, e.g. `width: 40%`.
You may specify an additional min-width, e.g. `min-width: 13em` to avoid wrapping on small screens.

Alternatively, you could use `white-space: nowrap;` to avoid line-breaks alltogether, then control the overflow behaviour with `overflow: visible`/`overflow: hidden`.

Comment: hmm ok the white-space:nowrap works. now, can i still have that and also set the cell to a certain size. what if i wanted a constant two lines (top and bottom) for the headers...regardless of the resolution

Comment: you could add <br> tags inside the <th> tags